# vbs: Elegant way to return array element?

Tags: vbscript

While I'm expecting a first and a last name as input for a vbscript I'm writing, sometimes the data will have both in a last name field, or it may contain a middle name as well. The separations between these could be commas or spaces. The data is pulled from an HL7 message.

The working method I'm using now is as follows:

```
Dim sLastName, sFirstName, sName, aName
sLastName = m.Element("PID-5-1").AsString
sFirstName = m.Element("PID-5-2").AsString

if sFirstName = "" then
  sName = fixName(sLastName)
  aName = split(sName, "*")
  sLastName = aName(0)
  sFirstName = aName(1)
end if

m.Element("PID-5-1").AsString = sLastName
m.Element("PID-5-1").AsString = sFirstName

'...rest of script, then fixName function...

Function fixName(sName)
  sName = LTrim(sName)
  sName = RTrim(sName)
  sName = replace(sName, ",", "*")
  sName = replace(sName, " ", "*")
  sName = replace(sName, "**", "*")
  fixName = sName
End Function
```

So this works, but it seems a bit inelegant. The script is already on the long side, and I have to perform this clean up in many places. I'm wondering if there is a way for me to perform the split in `fixName()` and return each part more directly? I tried sending a position variable to the function and then sending the appropriate array element based on that position, but I get an "subscript out of range" error when I do the split in `fixName()`.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to write something in the if statement like:

```
sFirstName = fixName(sLastName,1)
sLastName = fixName(sLastName,0)
```

How would you do it, or is what I have the best I can hope for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that such a function 'works':

```
>> Function getNamePart(s, i) : getNamePart = Split(s)(i) : End Function
>> s = "Alpha Beta Gamma"
>> WScript.Echo getNamePart(s, 0)
>> WScript.Echo getNamePart(s, 1)
>> WScript.Echo getNamePart(s, 2)
>>
Alpha
Beta
Gamma
```

and to demonstrate that you shouldn't use it - your CPU will hate you, if you force her to do the Split() (and the cleaning I left off) three times for one person.